# Eclipse Neon will not add include path

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, include

I have two projects in an eclipse workspace and one will add the include path for the boost libraries and one will not.

both projects use -std=c++11 I have included the include path in the c++ settings for both projects and it will not show up in the Includes section of one of the project.  I have no idea where to look to resolve this issue.

I can include other include paths and they work as one would expect.  I think it must have something to do with the boost libraries but I have no idea what to look for.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I just created a new project and copied all of the files over and it works perfectly, it must have been some problem with the project.  Sorry for the bother.